# As we prove that these two topologies in measures space $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{X})$ are really equals?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a complete metric space, $U(\mathbb{X})$ the space of bounded and continuous functions in $\mathbb{X}$ and $\mathcal{L}\big(U(\mathbb{X})\big)$ the space of all linear functionals $L:U(\mathbb{X})\to\mathbb{R}$.

> By definition, the weak topology of $U(\mathbb{X})$ is the smallest topology of $U(\mathbb{X})$ $\Big($"smallest" with respect to lower order  of inclusion "$\subset$" in $\{ \tau : \tau \mbox{ is topology of } U(\mathbb{X})\}$ $\Big)$ that makes continuous all linear functionals $L:U(\mathbb{X})\to\mathbb{R} $ of $\mathcal{L}\big(U(\mathbb{X})\big)$.

A linear functional $L\in\mathcal{L}\big(U(\mathbb{X})\big) $ is called positive if $f\geq 0$ implies $L(f)\geq 0$, $\forall f\in U(\mathbb{X})$. Let $\mathcal{L}_{\geq 0}\big( U(\mathbb{X})\big)$ the subspace of all linear functionals positives of $\mathcal{L}\big( U(\mathbb{X}) \big)$.

The Riesz Markov Theorem tells us that the space of positive linear functional $\mathcal{L}_{\geq 0}\big( U(\mathbb{X})\big)$ and $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{X})$ the space of measures with sign $\mu$ on Borel subsets of $\mathbb{X}$ are isomorphic. So it makes sense to speak of the weak topology of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{X})$ which is the topology induced by the isomorphism.

But several authors of books on probability in metric spaces ( see for exemple [Parthasarathy](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=IxOAqtJTx5MC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Parthasarathy&source=bl&ots=Ops3yLl8ic&sig=WmRynUNeXyLj8DsXDJWc-l09Uo0&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=5UxgULboDoey8ATZxICoDA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Parthasarathy&f=false) p. 40 ) define the weak topology in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{X})$ as that generated by the following system of neighborhoods:

$$
V_\mu \big( f_1,\dots,f_n,\epsilon_1,\dots\epsilon_n\big)=\bigg\{ \nu\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{X}) : \bigg| \int_{\mathbb{X}} f_i d\mu -\int_{\mathbb{X}}f_i d\nu \;\bigg|<\epsilon_i \bigg\}
$$
whit $ f_1,\dots,f_n\in U(\mathbb{X})$.

> **Question:** as we prove that these two topologies in space $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{X})$ are really equals?

Comment: vizinhaças ?????

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, sorry. "neighborhoods".

Comment: Aha, cognate with "vincinities" I guess. I should study other languages more. While we are at it, what do you mean by "signal"?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, Double sorry, "sign".

Comment: So: how would you write a base for the first topology?

Comment: @GEdgar well, a basic result of books functional analysis tells us that the  neighborhoods 
$V_f(L_1,\dots,L_n,\epsilon_1,\dots\epsilon_n)=\{g\in \mathcal{L}(U(\mathbb{X})) : |L_i(f)-L_i(g)|<\epsilon_i \} $ 
form a basis for weak topology of $\mathcal{L}_{\geq 0}(U(\mathbb{X}))$. But who this help me?

Comment: Show that the topology having these neighbors makes the elements of $\mathcal L(U(\mathbb X))$, then that is a topology make each element of $\mathcal L(U(\mathbb X))$ continuous, it necessarily have open set of the form you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write $V_f(L_1,\dots,L_n,\epsilon_1,\dots\epsilon_n)=\{g\in \mathcal{L}(U(\mathbb{X})) : |L_i(f)-L_i(g)|<\epsilon_i \}$.  That notation works where the elements of the space are called $f,g$ and the functionals are called $L_i$.  For the case of your question: elements of the space $\mathcal M(X)$ are called $\mu, \nu$ and functionals are written as $L_i(\mu) = \int f_i\,d\mu$